# Getting an unordered list to wrap around like in the picture here

Tags: html, css

I need to create a section that mimics the pictured mockup below

[image: what I need]

Because I'm using a content management system, I can only control the `CSS` of the elements in that section. So, for instance, I can't divide the `ul` into 2 `ul`s in separate `div`s (without using some fancy JavaScript hack).

What I need to work with is basically

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner-left">
       <!-- left content injected here by the CMS -->
   </div>
   <div class="inner-right">
         <!-- list content injected below by the CMS -->
         <ul></ul> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Off the top of your head, do you know an easy way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: .inner-right ul li { display: inline-block; float:left}

Comment: add a fixed width to the above comment and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a bunch of floating.

```
.inner-left {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%; // the first column width
}
.inner-right{
    float: left;
    width: 66.66%; // the container of the next 2 columns
}
```

Then we make the ul create the next 2 columns, but first you need to reset the ul by removing margin and padding, and then float the li and give them a width of 50%;

```
.inner-right ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.inner-right ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This should give you 3 evenly spaced columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
.inner-right ul li {
   display:inline-block;
   width:49%;
}
```